# How to add the digits in a number and place the result in a list

Tags: python, python-3.6

(sorry for bad title I had trouble sumerizing)So I'm working on a project where a have to take a list of completely random numbers, find the sum of digits in each number, and place that sum in a list. Here is what I have so far:

```
import random
import math
list1 = [random.randint(1,1000000000000) for i in range(0,10)]
list2 = []
list3 = []
def open_command():
    for y in range(0,10):
        a = list1[y]
        z = len(str(a))
        for x in range(0, z):
            f = len(str(a))
            b = a*0.1
            c, w=(math.modf(b))
            d = int(c*10)
            list2.append(d)
            a = (a - d)/10
            if f == 0:
                total = sum(list2)
                list3.append(total)
                list2.clear()
    

open_command()
print(list3)
```

When I run this code the list3 just displays an empty list however there is no error. I don't understand, Is the .append not working? Can somebody explain what is going on?

Comment: can you provide some examples of inputs with expected outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using map, One liner

```
list_num = [123,456]
print([sum(list(map(int, list(str(num))))) for num in list_num])
```

Output:

```
[6, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

That comes because the following code never got executed. List 3 is never appended and the list 2 never gots clear.

```
if f == 0:
    total = sum(list2)
    list3.append(total)
    list2.clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

You never change `a`, so the length of it (`f`) never becomes 0. Therefore, you never append anything.

But you're overcomplicating things:

```
list3 = [sum(int(char) for char in str(num)) for num in list1]
```

Or, if you want to keep your basic concept:

```
def open_command():
    for number in list1:
        for char in str(number):
            list2.append(int(char))
        list3.append(sum(list2))
        list2.clear()
    return list3
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. I can't use the one liners but you explained what was wrong and now its working.